# Setting :stdin with #+call in org-mode shell code block

Tags: org-babel, shell

I've got the following code:

```
#+NAME: example-block1
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
#+END_EXAMPLE

#+NAME: example-block2
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
#+END_EXAMPLE

#+NAME: my-shell-block
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :stdin example-block2
cat
#+END_SRC

#+CALL: my-shell-block()
```

Calling the "my-shell-block" with a hardcoded :stdin reference is no problem.

But now I want to set the :stdin dynamically in another "CALL":

```
#+CALL: my-shell-block(:stdin=example-block1)
```

This obviously does not work. Is there a way to dynamically change the ":stdin" of a shell code block?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*:stdin* isn't a argument as far as a function call is concerned. It's a special header argument which uses a [slightly funky #+CALL syntax](https://orgmode.org/manual/Arguments-in-function-calls.html). Try:

```
#+CALL: my-shell-block[:stdin example-block1]()
```

Depending on your results setting you might want to force it to take output so it doesn't listify your results:

```
#+CALL: my-shell-block[:stdin example-block1 :results output]()

#+RESULTS:
: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
```