# Supplying stdin input as a source block for CPP code as in shell script

Tags: org-babel

I am trying to supply code with stdin via a named example block using org-babel, as below (with [help](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46415/setting-stdin-with-call-in-org-mode-shell-code-block)):

```
#+NAME: read-to-stdin
#+begin_example
Hello, World!
#+end_example
```

The shell block

```
#+name: shell-program
#+header: :results output
#+begin_src sh
echo "here is content:"
value=$(cat)
echo "\"$value\""
#+end_src
```

can be called while passing contents from `read-to-stdin` as follows:

```
#+call: shell-program[:stdin read-to-stdin]()

#+RESULTS:
: here is content:
: "Hello, World!"
```

The same does not seem to be possible for a cpp program that is designed to do a similar thing:

```
#+name: cpp-program
#+header: :includes iostream
#+header: :results output
#+begin_src cpp
using namespace std;
cout << "here is content:" << endl;
string x;
cout << '"';
while (cin >> x) {
    cout << ' ' << x;
}
cout << '"' << endl;
#+end_src

#+call: cpp-program[:stdin read-to-stdin]()

#+RESULTS:
: here is content:
: ""

#+call: shell-program[:stdin read-to-stdin]()

#+RESULTS:
: here is content:
: ""
```

Is there some way of achieving this? If not, why not?